# Please suggest which method to go about in Forming UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a drop down list within a GridViewColumn

values include "item","item2"

When i click "item" value in Column,The next column must be editable
When i click on item2 the next column must have gridview structure again with 2 rows and three columns  or someway to input 6 values.

Is this possible??Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use second column as `DataGridTemplateColumn` and switch the contenttemplate depending on value of selected item in combobox. But you should have your model backing datagridrow as `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented and SelectedItemBinding of combobox column should be bind to property on your model.

```
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value2}"/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="CellEditingTemplate">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value2}"/>
                </DataTemplate>

            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Value1}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}">

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="myControl"/>
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value2}" Value="item1">
                                    <Setter TargetName="myControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CellEditingTemplate}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value2}" Value="item2">
                                    <Setter TargetName="myControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CellTemplate}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```